# How to know the interactions happened with the feed in stream?

Tags: c#, getstream-io

My query goes like this: If I have a feedItem (an image posted on facebook), how can I verify that I have liked it or not? Can I verify all the interactions which I have done to the feedItem or the interactions other people have done to it (`like, dislike, pin, share`)? Is there any way in `getstream.io` to retrieve these interactions?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: the answer should be in facebook. they provide API for authorized developers and websites.

Comment: @Dongdong Thanks for the reply. Actually I want to know, how it is done on getstream.io because I am using the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) provides all functions you need. Here are some examples:

1. Read `shares`[it's a field of an object]: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/post#read
2. Read `Shared posts`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/object/sharedposts
3. read `likes`:
   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/object/likes#read

> /likes returns only the profile for the current user if read with a
>   user access token:
>
> Album, Photo, Post, Video

all returns are JSON, which you can directly [Deserialize Anonymous Type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) without using stream, for example, `likes`:

```
  {
  "likes": {
    "data": [
      {
        "name": "Bill the Cat",
        "id": "155111347875779",
        "created_time": "2017-06-18T18:21:04+0000"
      },
      {
        "name": "Calvin and Hobbes",
        "id": "257573197608192",
        "created_time": "2017-06-18T18:21:02+0000"
      },
      {
        "name": "Berkeley Breathed's Bloom County",
        "id": "108793262484769",
        "created_time": "2017-06-18T18:20:58+0000"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "cursors": {
        "before": "Nzc0Njg0MTQ3OAZDZD",
        "after": "NTcxODc1ODk2NgZDZD"
      },
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/vX.X/me/likes?access_token=user-access-token&pretty=0&summary=true&limit=25&after=NTcxODc1ODk2NgZDZD"
    },
    "summary": {
      "total_count": 136
    }
  },
  "id": "user-id"
}
```